# Order by 6 digit to 7 digit value then from lowest to highest

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This code attempts to sort my values by number of digits, from 6 to 7, then from lowest to highest numerically.

```
SELECT * FROM score ORDER BY ID DESC
```

I have sets of data in my table and I always get:

| ID |
| --- |
| 992425 |
| 992199 |
| 1001111 |

I expect result

| ID |
| --- |
| 992199 |
| 992425 |
| 1001111 |

How to sort by number of digits, from 6 to 7, then ID from lowest to highest numerically?

The ID column is an `NVARCHAR` column.

Comment: What's the datatype of ID? It appears to be VARCHAR.

Comment: What's the type of your ID Column? and you seem like want to use ASC instead of DESC

Comment: @Dale K, Sorry, no clear explanation. Yes i meant  number of digits. but it is work now when reference your suggest. thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have your `integer` data stored in `nvarchar` column there are chances of `cast` getting failed due to other than `integer` value in your column.

I would suggest using `try_cast` as follows:

```
select * from score 
ORDER BY try_cast(ID as int)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are ordering strings and not their numerical values. Also `DESC` orders in reverse order. To fix that, convert `ID` to `INT`:

```
SELECT CAST(ID AS INT)
FROM score
ORDER BY ID ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to order first by the length of the string, then by the numerical value of the string.

```
select id
from (
  values('992425'),('992199'),('1001111')
) x (id)
order by len(id) asc, cast(id as int) asc;
```

Returns:

| id |
| --- |
| 992199 |
| 992425 |
| 1001111 |